# tbody width not automatically extending to width of table

Tags: html, css, html-table, reset

Take a look at this example here:

http://denise.brixwork.com/showlisting/1/8297-Valley-Drive-Alpine-Meadows-Whistler-denise-brown-real-estate

And the red tables under "Specifications" is not becoming the full width of the  containing it - when inspecting on Firebug, the  div is not 220 pixels, but rather, just over a 100 pixels based on the content width.

```
<div class="grid_4 alpha">
    <table width="100%" class="grid_4 alpha omega">
            <tr class="specrow">
            <td class="specname">type:</td>
            <td class="specvalue">House</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="specrow">
            <td class="specname">year:</td>
            <td class="specvalue">1986</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The CSS code looks like this:

```
#listing_specs table {
    width: 100%;
}

#listing_specs table tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    width: 100%;
}

.specrow {
    margin:2px 0px;
    border-bottom:1px dotted #dadada;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #A92229;
}

.specrow:hover {
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
}

.specname{
    font-weight: 600;
    padding:2px 2px 2px 5px;
    width: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.specvalue {
    font-weight:normal;
    padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
    text-align:left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I know there is a generic CSS resetter, and I think that's what's causing the problem. Unfortunately I can't go and just remove the reference to it because multiple sites refer to it from the same location at this moment, and I can't just make that change without careful review. So I need a way to override it on the stylesheet itself. The reset CSS being called is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://demo.brixwork.com/master/css/reset.css" />
```

Comment: if anyone else found this from google, fyi, border-collapse: separate + border-spacing means that it adds margin to the outside of the table. counteract this with negative margin.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

you should just add

```
display: table;
```

under this selector:

```
#listing_specs table { }
```

Comment: yep i spoiled it with display: inline-block - but i could have used display: inline-table too instead

Answer (score 22):

You can use this code

```
tbody{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: This was the good answer for me

Comment: This helped me, and the `width:100%` is important if you have two tables inline and you want to center them

Answer (score 11):

The table inherits display:inline;

It should be: display:table;

The part cousing the display:inline is:

```
.grid_1, .grid_2, .grid_3, .grid_4, 
.grid_5, .grid_6, .grid_7, .grid_8, 
.grid_9, .grid_10, .grid_11, .grid_12, 
.grid_13, .grid_14, .grid_15, .grid_16 {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ah i see the conflict there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use inline CSS like as `style="display: table"`

I'm using this format and it works fine.